# I get this weird error using quick-xml deserialization: failed to ds the xml: UnexpectedStart([77, 101, 115, 115, 97, 103, 101])

Tags: xml, parsing, rust

I'm using the evtx library to read through the .evtx file format and try to parse the given xml into rust object, for this purpose I decided to go with quick-xml(serialize feature) to achieve my goal, however I get this error message and can't wrap my head around it.

main.rs :

```
fn main() {
    let fp = PathBuf::from("/Users/arshiamohammadi/Documents/rust/evtx_parser/records/logs1.evtx");

    let mut parser = EvtxParser::from_path(fp).unwrap();
    for record in parser.records() {
        match record {
            Ok(r) => {
                //output_file.write_all(r.data.as_bytes()).expect("Failed to write to the file");
                let event: Event = from_str(&r.data).expect("failed to ds the xml");
                println!("{:#?}", event);
            },
            Err(e) => eprintln!("{}", e),
        }
        break;
    }
}
```

deserialization:

```
use serde::Deserialize;

#[derive(Debug, Deserialize)]
#[serde(rename_all = "PascalCase")]
pub struct Event {
    system: System,
    event_data: EventData,
    rendering_info: RenderingInfo,
}

#[derive(Debug, Deserialize)]
#[serde(rename_all = "PascalCase")]
struct System {
    //provider: Provider,
    EventID: String,
    version: String,
    level: String,
    task: String,
    opcode: String,
    keywords: String,
    time_created: TimeCreated,
    EventRecordID: String,
    channel: String,
    computer: String,
    security: String,
}


#[derive(Debug, Deserialize)]
#[serde(rename_all = "PascalCase")]
struct TimeCreated {
    #[serde(rename = "@SystemTime")]
    system_time: String,
}


#[derive(Debug, Deserialize)]
#[serde(rename_all = "PascalCase")]
struct EventData {
    data: Vec<Data>,
}

#[derive(Debug, Deserialize)]
#[serde(rename_all = "PascalCase")]
struct Data {
    #[serde(rename = "$value")]
    value: String,
    #[serde(rename = "@Name")]
    name: String,
}


#[derive(Debug, Deserialize)]
#[serde(rename_all = "PascalCase")]
struct RenderingInfo {
    #[serde(rename = "@Culture")]
    culture: String,
    #[serde(rename = "$value")]
    message: String,
}
```

the xml file(r.data in this case):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
  <System>
    <Provider Name="Microsoft-Windows-Security-Auditing" Guid="{54849625-5478-4994-a5ba-3e3b0328c30d}">
    </Provider>
    <EventID>4624</EventID>
    <Version>2</Version>
    <Level>0</Level>
    <Task>12544</Task>
    <Opcode>0</Opcode>
    <Keywords>0x8020000000000000</Keywords>
    <TimeCreated SystemTime="2023-02-01T09:50:18.6688288Z">
    </TimeCreated>
    <EventRecordID>659653170</EventRecordID>
    <Correlation ActivityID="{36ca3399-1428-0000-f669-ca362814d901}">
    </Correlation>
    <Execution ProcessID="1484" ThreadID="16260">
    </Execution>
    <Channel>Security</Channel>
    <Computer>THRMAIL120024.ULI.com</Computer>
    <Security>
    </Security>
  </System>
  <EventData>
    <Data Name="SubjectUserSid">S-1-0-0</Data>
    <Data Name="SubjectUserName">-</Data>
    <Data Name="SubjectDomainName">-</Data>
    <Data Name="SubjectLogonId">0x0</Data>
    <Data Name="TargetUserSid">S-1-5-21-158521042-2690386519-1069000242-6728</Data>
    <Data Name="TargetUserName">asaad.abbaspour</Data>
    <Data Name="TargetDomainName">ULI</Data>
    <Data Name="TargetLogonId">0x2367bc2f9</Data>
    <Data Name="LogonType">3</Data>
    <Data Name="LogonProcessName">NtLmSsp </Data>
    <Data Name="AuthenticationPackageName">NTLM</Data>
    <Data Name="WorkstationName">AWZL1004000633</Data>
    <Data Name="LogonGuid">{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}</Data>
    <Data Name="TransmittedServices">-</Data>
    <Data Name="LmPackageName">NTLM V2</Data>
    <Data Name="KeyLength">128</Data>
    <Data Name="ProcessId">0x0</Data>
    <Data Name="ProcessName">-</Data>
    <Data Name="IpAddress">152.109.247.7</Data>
    <Data Name="IpPort">49900</Data>
    <Data Name="ImpersonationLevel">%%1833</Data>
    <Data Name="RestrictedAdminMode">-</Data>
    <Data Name="TargetOutboundUserName">-</Data>
    <Data Name="TargetOutboundDomainName">-</Data>
    <Data Name="VirtualAccount">%%1843</Data>
    <Data Name="TargetLinkedLogonId">0x0</Data>
    <Data Name="ElevatedToken">%%1842</Data>
  </EventData>
  <RenderingInfo Culture="en-US">
    <Message>An account was successfully logged on.

Subject:
    Security ID:        S-1-0-0
    Account Name:       -
    Account Domain:     -
    Logon ID:       0x0

Logon Information:
    Logon Type:     3
    Restricted Admin Mode:  -
    Virtual Account:        No
    Elevated Token:     Yes

Impersonation Level:        Impersonation

New Logon:
    Security ID:        S-1-5-21-158521042-2690386519-1069000242-6728
    Account Name:       asaad.abbaspour
    Account Domain:     ULI
    Logon ID:       0x2367BC2F9
    Linked Logon ID:        0x0
    Network Account Name:   -
    Network Account Domain: -
    Logon GUID:     {00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}

Process Information:
    Process ID:     0x0
    Process Name:       -

Network Information:
    Workstation Name:   AWZL1004000633
    Source Network Address: 152.109.247.7
    Source Port:        49900

Detailed Authentication Information:
    Logon Process:      NtLmSsp 
    Authentication Package: NTLM
    Transited Services: -
    Package Name (NTLM only):   NTLM V2
    Key Length:     128

This event is generated when a logon session is created. It is generated on the computer that was accessed.

The subject fields indicate the account on the local system which requested the logon. This is most commonly a service such as the Server service, or a local process such as Winlogon.exe or Services.exe.

The logon type field indicates the kind of logon that occurred. The most common types are 2 (interactive) and 3 (network).

The New Logon fields indicate the account for whom the new logon was created, i.e. the account that was logged on.

The network fields indicate where a remote logon request originated. Workstation name is not always available and may be left blank in some cases.

The impersonation level field indicates the extent to which a process in the logon session can impersonate.

The authentication information fields provide detailed information about this specific logon request.
    - Logon GUID is a unique identifier that can be used to correlate this event with a KDC event.
    - Transited services indicate which intermediate services have participated in this logon request.
    - Package name indicates which sub-protocol was used among the NTLM protocols.
    - Key length indicates the length of the generated session key. This will be 0 if no session key was requested.</Message>
    <Level>Information</Level>
    <Task>Logon</Task>
    <Opcode>Info</Opcode>
    <Channel>Security</Channel>
    <Provider>Microsoft Windows security auditing.</Provider>
    <Keywords>
      <Keyword>Audit Success</Keyword>
    </Keywords>
  </RenderingInfo>
</Event>
```

Comment: Not sure, but those bytes are ASCII `Message`

Comment: @BallpointBen hahaha turns out the xml <Message> elements closing tag were missing thanks for pointing this out.